# Validation of checkboxes with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need to show an error if none of the below checkboxes are checked using using JavaScript.

```html
<tr>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="single" id="chk_stat">single

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="married" id="chk_stat">Married

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="divorcee" id="chk_stat">Divorcee

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="student" id="chk_stat">Student
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `var anychecked = $('input[name="chk_stat[]"]').is(':checked')`

Comment: Anyway this should be re-opened because the other Q&A isn't using vanilla JS...

Comment: @ArunPJohny what should be the next line?

Comment: @DewDrop sorry, missed that there is no jQuery tag

Comment: @ArunPJohny : how can check and where should i write error msg after var anychecked = $('input[name="chk_stat[]"]').is(':checked')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it using selecting all elements with some given name using `document.querySelectorAll` and an attribute selector using the pseudoclass `:checked`:

```js
var checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("[name='chk_stat[]']:checked");

if (checkedCheckboxes.length == 0) {
  console.log("No checkbox is checked...");
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="single" id="chk_stat">single

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="married" id="chk_stat">Married

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="divorcee" id="chk_stat">Divorcee

    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_stat[]" value="student" id="chk_stat">Student
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help